# Django form post not saving

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am making a Django application (for the first time in my life). As part of the application, a timetable needs to be implemented. Loading data (from the databse) into the timetable works fine:
[Timetable view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA4NQ.png)

The thing is that the data should be editable. So users need to be able to change the time or the yes/no parameter. I've created a POST handler in views.py, but when I press save, the page quickly reloads and the old values are back. What am I doing wrong?

models.py

```
class timeTable(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, null=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.key
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def timetable(request):
    timeTableFormset = modelformset_factory(timeTable, fields='__all__' ,extra=0)
    timetableform = timeTableFormset(queryset=timeTable.objects.all()) 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = timeTableFormset(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    return render(request, 'VulnManager/timetable.html', {'timetableform': timetableform})
```

timetable.html:

```
<form method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <table id="tablePreview" class="table table-borderless table-hover">
                            <!--Table head-->
                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th></th>
                                  <th>Monday</th>
                                  <th>Tuesday</th>
                                  <th>Wednesday</th>
                                  <th>Thursday</th>
                                  <th>Friday</th>
                                  <th>Saturday</th>
                                  <th>Sunday</th>
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <!--Table head-->
                              <!--Table body-->
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">Scan?</th>
                                    {{ timetableform.management_form }}
                                    {% for timeTableValue in timetableform.forms %}
                                    {% if forloop.counter <= 7 %}
                                    <td><select class="form-control" id="{{ timeTableValue.key.value }}" disabled="true">
                                        <option>{{ timeTableValue.value.value }}</option>
                                        <option>
                                            {% if timeTableValue.value.value == "true" %}
                                            false
                                            {% elif timeTableValue.value.value == "false" %}
                                            true
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </option>
                                    </select></td>
                                    {% if forloop.counter == 7 %}
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">Time begin</th>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% elif forloop.counter >= 8 and forloop.counter <= 14 %}
                                    <td><input type="text" id="{{ timeTableValue.key.value }}" onchange="validateHhMm(this);" value="{{ timeTableValue.value.value }}" readonly /></td>
                                    {% if forloop.counter == 14 %}
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">Time end</th>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% elif forloop.counter >= 15 and forloop.counter <= 21 %}
                                    <td><input type="text" id="{{ timeTableValue.key.value }}" onchange="validateHhMm(this);" value="{{ timeTableValue.value.value }}" readonly /></td>
                                    {% endif %} 
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </tr>
                              </tbody>
                              <!--Table body-->
                            </table>
                            <input type="button" class="btn-primary" id="edit" value="Edit" />
                            <input type="submit" class="btn-primary" id="save" value="Save" />
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "form" variable has the formset in it, but you have to loop through the forms in the formset individually:

```
if form.is_valid():
    for form_line in form:
        form_line.save()
```

Comment: I've tried this, this does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your view is always rendering the "get" form for lack of a better term.

I think if you keep your variable names the same, it'll make things a bit simpler and consistent. So to explain this;

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def timetable(request):
    timeTableFormset = modelformset_factory(timeTable, fields='__all__' ,extra=0)
    timetableform = timeTableFormset(queryset=timeTable.objects.all()) 

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = timeTableFormset(request.POST) # This form just gets left in this block
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    return render(
        request,
        'VulnManager/timetable.html',
        {'timetableform': timetableform}  # The context includes the fresh new form, with no post data
    )
```

What you should do, is just call it `formset`, because it makes life easier;

```
from django.contrib import messages


@login_required(login_url='login')
def timetable(request):
    timeTableFormset = modelformset_factory(timeTable, fields='__all__' ,extra=0)

    formset = timeTableFormset(queryset=timeTable.objects.all()) 

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = timeTableFormset(data=request.POST, queryset=timeTable.objects.all())
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            # Do something here to reassure the user it saved. Redirect or add a message
            messages.success(request, 'Form saved.')

    return render(
        request,
        'VulnManager/timetable.html',
        {'timetableform': formset}
    )
```

There's an article here which may provide some worthy reading for you; https://medium.com/@MicroPyramid/understanding-djangos-model-fromsets-in-detail-and-their-advanced-usage-131dfe66853d

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I use this. After updating, it shows "None" as values in the template. What can cause this?

Comment: Very hard to say. Does it update your data? If it does, I'd add a redirect after the save to send the user somewhere else that they'd likely go after saving.

Comment: Forgot to say; no it doesn't save the data. It says 'None'. When reloading page old data is back. When pressing F5, browser attends me that I have unsaved data.